# Is there an excel formula that will round negative numbers up? i.e. round(-2.5) = -2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Microsoft Office Excel 2010 rounds 2.5 to 3. It also rounds -2.5 to -3.

I'm trying to use Excel validate my data against a system that rounds -2.5 to -2. Different systems seem to use different tie breaking rules (i.e. I learned the hard way that Oracle use opposite rules).

Is there an Excel formula that will round -2.5 to -2? Creativity is also acceptable (i.e. simple macro).

It should also round:

```
-2.7 -> -3
-2.2 -> -2
```

This rounds in the opposite direction that I'm looking for:

```
=ROUND(-2.5,0)
```

EDIT: I previously said that one type of rounding is more correct than another. After more research, I didn't one more popular than another. But I did find the default [IEEE rounding rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/rules-for-rounding-positive-and-negative-numbers), which is strangely, break ties by rounding to the nearest half number. I'm not looking for this method though :)

Comment: Well, if the rule is to round up, he's got a point.

Comment: Your statement on Excel being incorrect made me look it up.  According to http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/rounding-methods.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding, Excel is just choosing a more commonly used rounding method. They are both valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's always whole numbers this should work.

```
=FLOOR(A1+0.5,1)
```

If you need decimals say the number of decimals is in B1 it's as simple as

```
=FLOOR(A1*10^B1+0.5,1)/10^B1
```

As barry Houdini pointed out in the comments FLOOR(, 1) is the same as INT() but without the extra parameter.

```
=INT(A1*10^B1+0.5)/10^B1
```

Comment: INT is probably better since you don't have to pass in the 1 as a second parameter.  I do believe FLOOR(x, 1) is the same as INT(x) in Excel.  Good point.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be the following:

```
IF(A1 >= 0; ROUND(A1; 0); -ROUND(-A1; 0))
```

Comment: That's not what he meant. This rounds everything down.

Comment: @pnuts, `CEILING` also not working since OP wants `-2.7 -> -3`, but `=CEILING(-2.7,1)=-2`

Comment: Can IF(A1 >= 0) THEN ROUND(A1; 0) ELSE (ROUND(A1*-1; 0))* -1) be written a single excel formula?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as well.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(".5",A1)),ROUNDDOWN(A1,0),ROUND(A1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very pretty, but this works. You can change the precision accordingly to the precision of the numbers you're working with.

```
IF(A1 >= 0; ROUND(A1; 0); ROUND(ROUND(A1-0.999999; 0)+.999999; 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use **IF()** with **INT()** to evaluate whether the number is positive or negative by converting to positive first, then converting back afterwards.

**Pseudo-code**

```
// positive number evaluation
If decimal is greater than or equals 0, then INT( decimal )

// negative number evaluation
Else INT( number × (-1) ) × (-1)
```

**Excel If() and INT() Functions**

```
=IF( number >= 0, INT( number ), INT( ( number ) * (-1) ) * (-1) )
```

**Positive Number Example**

```
=IF(2.5>=0,INT(2.5),INT((2.5)*(-1))*(-1))
=2
```

**Negative Number Example**

```
=IF(-2.5>=0,INT(-2.5),INT((-2.5)*(-1))*(-1))
=-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try formula TRUNC

=TRUNC(-2.5)

Comment: This would result in the correct answer for this specific value, but not in case of the positive equivalent of the number: `2.5` here `3` would be expected. But this question has been answered (in 2014!).